# Handling null values in linear regression, which are suppose to be higher than the non-null values

Tags: regression, data-imputation, censoring

I am currently doing a linear regression, where i try to predict the housing prices based on different variables that describe the house's spatial features (such as the distance to the closest city, the closest road etc.).

My problem is, one of the original datasets have only calculated the distance to the closest road if the road is within a 2 km radius of the house. so any house which do not have a road closer than 2 km  to it have gotten a NULL value instead of the distance.

I was therefore wondering, is it possible to replace these null values? for example with some value above 2 km?

Comment: This will be tricky... First I need you to explain why your profile picture is  Thyra Frank

Comment: There is a tag on this site [tag:interval-censoring] which contains some threads which may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to include a dummy if the values are missing. If it is significant you can conclude that living more than 2km from a road (decreases, probably) the value of the house.